# Spring Data Mongodb 3.0.3 problem with doing a count with a near query

Tags: spring-data-mongodb

```
GeoJsonPoint point = new GeoJsonPoint(78.850300, 35.732700);
Query query = new Query();      query.addCriteria(Criteria.where(FIELD_LOCATION_LONGLAT).near(point).minDistance(0.0).maxDistance(10000.0));
            
mongoTemplate.forTenant(mcsRequest.getCustomer()).find(query, DBTower.class, TOWERS_COLLECTION);

mongoTemplate.forTenant(mcsRequest.getCustomer()).count(query, DBTower.class, TOWERS_COLLECTION);
```

The find works, but the count gets this error

org.springframework.data.mongodb.UncategorizedMongoDbException: Command failed with error 2 (BadValue): 'Point must only contain numeric elements' on server localhost:27017. The full response is {"ok": 0.0, "errmsg": "Point must only contain numeric elements", "code": 2, "codeName": "BadValue"}; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 2 (BadValue): 'Point must only contain numeric elements' on server localhost:27017. The full response is {"ok": 0.0, "errmsg": "Point must only contain numeric elements", "code": 2, "codeName": "BadValue"}

I notice that the CountQuery class is turning my $near query to a $geoWithin, it didnt do that before.

Comment: can you please share the json query sent to the server? Seems to be related to [DATAMONGO-2059](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAMONGO-2059)

Comment: Did you find a solution yet?